# "echarts"' has no exported member named 'EChartOption'. Did you mean 'EChartsOption' instead?

Tags: javascript, angular, echarts, ngx-echarts

I am using **Angular 9** along with `"ngx-echarts": "5.2.2"` and `"echarts": "5.0.0"`

Everything works fine accept while setting `icon: 'circle'` for legends. It says below thing.

> Type '{ icon: string; top: string; left: string; orient: "vertical";
> }' is not assignable to type 'LegendOption | ScrollableLegendOption |
> (LegendOption | ScrollableLegendOption)[]'.

As per example in [ngx-echarts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-echarts/v/5.2.2#usage) I can't use `import { EChartOption } from 'echarts'`;

I have checked that icon is available in **EchartOption** instead of Echart`s`Option

Is there anything i am missing?

After installing [@types/echarts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/echarts) my code is working and showing legend with circle icon but have random error that it can't find EchartOption in echarts (My angular is not taking care of this and running application by ignoring this error)

RIght now i went with `import { EChartsOption } from 'echarts';` and removed @types/echarts library. And i can't change legend icon for the moment :(
Any help?

Thanks,
Jayesh

Comment: You should include the code that causes the issue, so that we can see the types that you try to use

Comment: in my EchartOption config, I want a option which can convert my legends to circle instead of rectangle. Does code required for that?

Comment: Of course - how should anyone know what's wrong with your code, when we cannot see it?. It would be even better when you create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When yo use echarts 5 you MUST NOT install @types/echarts, because echarts 5 is now written in typescript: i.e. the echarts package already includes the correct types for this version.

There have been many changes between echarts 4 and echarts5 - one of them is that EchartOption is now called EchartsOption (with plural "s")

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import * as echarts from 'echarts';

type EChartsOption = echarts.EChartsOption;
```

You can find code example here: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&lang=ts, click `Full Code` tab